# reusing a stringstream to parse values from multiple strings in succession

Tags: c++

I am trying to read in data from a text file but am not getting the right values. Only the values of width0 and height0 and width1 height 1 are right. All the values after the 2nd line are wrong. Can anyone tell me why ?

```
string line, thrash;    
std::istringstream in;
ifstream myfile("camera_parameters.txt");

float width0, height0, width1, height1; // Initial and Final image sizes
float fx1, fy1, cx1, cy1;   // L camera matrix
float fx2, fy2, cx2, cy2;   // R camera matrix
float a1, b1, c1, d1, e1;   // L camera distortion matrix
float a2, b2, c2, d2, e2;   // R camera distortion matrix
float tx, ty, tz;           // Trans from L to R camera
float r00, r01, r02,        // Rotat from L to R camera
      r10, r11, r12, 
      r20, r21, r22;

std::getline(myfile, line); in.str(line);
in >> thrash;
in >> width0 >> height0;
in.str(""); in.clear();

std::getline(myfile, line); in.str(line);
in >> thrash; 
in >> width1 >> height1;
in.str(""); in.clear();

std::getline(myfile, line); in.str(line);
in >> thrash;
in >> tx >> ty >> tz;
in.str(""); in.clear();
cout << tx << " " << ty << endl;

std::getline(myfile, line); in.str(line);
in >> thrash;
in >> r00 >> r01 >> r02 >> r10 >> r11 >> r12 >> r20 >> r21 >> r22;
in.clear(); in.str(std::string());

std::getline(myfile, line); in.str(line);
in >> thrash;
in >> fx1 >> thrash >> cx1 >> thrash >> fy1 >> cy1;
in.clear(); in.str(std::string());

std::getline(myfile, line); in.str(line);
in >> thrash;
in >> a1 >> b1 >> c1 >> d1 >> e1;
in.clear(); in.str(std::string());

std::getline(myfile, line); in.str(line);
in >> thrash;
in >> fx2 >> thrash >> cx2 >> thrash >> fy2 >> cy2;
in.clear(); in.str(std::string());

std::getline(myfile, line); in.str(line);
in >> thrash;
in >> a2 >> b2 >> c2 >> d2 >> e2;
in.clear(); in.str(std::string());
```

Below are my data in a text file

```
S_00: 1.392000e+03 5.120000e+02
S_rect_00: 1.242000e+03 3.750000e+02    
T_01: -5.370000e-01 4.822061e-03 -1.252488e-02    
R_01: 9.993513e-01 1.860866e-02 -3.083487e-02 -1.887662e-02 9.997863e-01 -8.421873e-03 3.067156e-02 8.998467e-03 9.994890e-01    
K_00: 9.842439e+02 0.000000e+00 6.900000e+02 0.000000e+00 9.808141e+02 2.331966e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00    
D_00: -3.728755e-01 2.037299e-01 2.219027e-03 1.383707e-03 -7.233722e-02    
K_01: 9.895267e+02 0.000000e+00 7.020000e+02 0.000000e+00 9.878386e+02 2.455590e+02 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00    
D_01: -3.644661e-01 1.790019e-01 1.148107e-03 -6.298563e-04 -5.314062e-02
```

Comment: Well, debug it.  Print out each value (including the entire line stored in the `line` variable) as you read it, and see what goes wrong.  Also check failbit.

Comment: It seems like at the 2nd line, getline reads in the correct line (S_rect_00: 1.242000e+03 3.750000e+02 ) but in >> thrash reads in S_00...

Comment: Closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/16443153/103167

Comment: You have serious code smells 1) Declaring variables at the beginning of a function (instead of declaring each right at usage) 2) Dealing with too many variables in a single function (split that function)

Comment: Seems like im not able to get it right even after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848087/how-to-clear-stringstream what a pos function

Comment: So no one has any idea how to get this function working ? is it no longer in use ? is there a different function to read things from txt files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `in >> width0 >> height0;`, the EOF flag is set on `in`, which will prevent any further usage.

Associating the stream with new data via `in.str(line)` doesn't reset the flags, you will have to do that yourself via `in.clear()`.

Comment: @kong: You're still not telling us how far it gets before it goes wrong.

Comment: Hi thanks ! The values of tx ty tz (3rd line onwards) are all wrong. Maybe it'll be easier to just create a new stringstream everytime. This task is so much easier in matlab

Comment: Hi its working now. I don't know why but I just had to restart visual studio I think... Thanks :)